# Missing plugin icon when installing Crashlytics 1.3 plugin for Android on Eclipse 4.2 Juno

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, crashlytics

Trying to install `Crashlytics` 1.3 plugin on Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)

Downloaded the plugin from https://crashlytics.com/download/eclipse

Installation completed okay.

I've checked that the plugin is in place:
`Crashlytics's com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse.workbench_1.3.0.201312161704.jar in eclipse\plugins subfolder, also eclipse\features\com.crashlytics.tools.eclipse_1.3.0 subfolder.`

When restarting the plugin icon was missing from the bar

I've checked the Window > Customize Perspective and > Tool Bar Visibility and there was no Crashlytics item to select.

What's wrong? where is the icon?

Thanks.

Using:
ADT 22.3, 
Windows 7